# Android Java to PHP String Literal Issue when using MY_SQL

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sql

I am trying to use PHP to do queries for a Android App I am creating however I am having problems with the nested quotes that I have when calling my code. Let me show you what I am trying to do
My php code is as followed:

```
<?php

$theQuery = $_POST['query'];

if(sizeOfArray == 0){
    $clause = "";
}

$con = mysql_connect("localhost" , "localuser" , "NOTMYPASSWORD");

if(!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("localuser_MyApp" , $con);

$result = mysql_query($theQuery);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output[] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

This is the String literal that I am using in Java. I am passing this String to PHP through the POST method. However this query doesn't work because of the single quotes in the where clause.

```
"SELECT I.id , I.name, I.price 
FROM Item I 
INNER JOIN Item_Menu IM ON I.id = IM.itemid 
INNER JOIN Menu_Type MT ON MT.id= IM.menuid 
WHERE MT.name='entrees'";
```

I tried using the following but this also doesn't work. I get a warning about how the result returned was not a proper SQL result.

```
"SELECT I.id , I.name, I.price 
FROM Item I 
INNER JOIN Item_Menu IM ON I.id = IM.itemid 
INNER JOIN Menu_Type MT ON MT.id= IM.menuid 
WHERE MT.name=\"entrees\"";
```

If I use an id instead or remove the WHERE clause instead of using an actual String value then the query works fine.

My questions is how can I format this query correctly in java so I can pass it to php properly? More information can be provided if necessary but I didn't want to overload this question with blocks of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the query in with the double quotes (like you have above). Then in PHP, `str_replace` the double quotes with single quotes

```
$theQuery = str_replace("\"", "'", $_POST['query']);
```

Comment: This is a great idea and helped me with my work around. For some reason replacing "\ didn't actually replace the "\ from the java so instead I surrounded entrees with ?!?entrees?!? and then did a replace all with ?!? as suggested and that worked. Thanks a bunch.